# How to prevent JQM from resizing screen on rotate?

Tags: jquery-mobile, media-queries

I am building a website for smartphones and tablets using JQM. I have a page which shows a Google map using [gmap3](http://gmap3.net/). I am using @media to define the size of the #map_canvas based on screen resolution.

Everything is working perfectly well, except that when the device's orientation is changed, the page gets zoomed-in (enlarged). How can I fix this?

**Portrait view with no problems (iPhone 4)**

[image: Portrait]

**When the phone is rotated, the page gets enlarged. But when the page is called in landscape view, it looks fine.**

[image: Landscape]

Here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Map</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"> 

<!--JS and CSS links where removed to save space-->

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    $('#map_canvas').gmap3({
 marker:{
latLng:[36.491025,-4.951299],
  options:{
  center:[36.491025,-4.951299]
  },
},          
    map:{
  address:"Puerto Banus, Marbella, Spain",
  options:{
    zoom:16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControl: true,
    scrollwheel: true,
    streetViewControl: true
  }
}

    });
  });

</script>
```

Page structure

```
<body> 
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
<div data-role="header"><h1>Map Page</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content" id="map_canvas">
</div> <!-- /content-->
</div> <!-- /page-->

</body>
```

@media query

```
<style>
#map_canvas {
height: 768px;
width: 1024px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
}

@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
#map_canvas {
height: 768px;
width: 1024px;
 }
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
#map_canvas {
height: 768px;
width: 1024px;
  }
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
#map_canvas {
width: 768px;
height: 1024px;
  }
}

/* iPhone 4 - (portrait) ---------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (orientation:portrait),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)  and (orientation:portrait){
   #map_canvas {
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: auto;
 }
}

/* iPhone 4 - (landscape) ---------- */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (orientation:landscape), screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (orientation:landscape){
#map_canvas {
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: auto;
  }
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px)
and (max-width: 480px) {
  #map_canvas {
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: auto;
  }
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
    #map_canvas {
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: auto;
    }
}

</style>
```

**EDIT:** Added photo of a landscape view on initial load.

[image: Landscape initial]

Comment: What happens if you load the page initially in landscape (rather than rotating after the page has already loaded)?

Comment: @AdamD It loads perfectly well. I will add a photo of landscape view shortly.

Comment: So then when you load in landscape, and then rotate to portrait, I'm assuming you have the same issue?

Comment: @AdamD The margins of the page change but it doesn't zoom-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out using [jquery-ui-map](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/). It might be a better way than `gmap3`

Comment: Thanks @Adam I will check it and will let you know.

Comment: Sorry @Adam nothing has changed. The problem presists.

Comment: Here's my new code. `<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
                var yourStartLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.491025,-4.951299); //Centers
                $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': yourStartLatLng});
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'zoom', 16);
    $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(evt, map) { 
          $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { /*id:'m_1',*/ 'position': '36.491025,-4.951299', 'bounds': false } ); //Marker
    });
        });
</script>`

Comment: I got it fixed @AdamD. The `#map_canvas` should be in a separate div not in the same `content` div. So the answer is `<div data-role="content"><div id="map_canvas"></div> <!-- /map_canvas-->
</div> <!-- /content-->`

Answer (score 0):

You can force your viewer to look at your site in landscape mode.  You can see what I did at https://www.bluepitt.com  where if your looking at the site in portrait, I have a picture that covers up the site that tells the viewer to rotate to landscape.  When they turn to look at landscape, the picture disappears and your designed page displays.  Here is the code you place in the body of your site:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- your html for your website -->
</div>

<div id="warning-message">

<img src="warning.png" width="1000" height="1770" alt=""/> </div>
```